# adding a same header to multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe which shape is (12,75000). I made this dataframe by concatinating 3 separate np.arrays which has no headers.
Now, I want to deducate a specific header to each np.array that I concatenated to make my dataframe like the image that I attached. [image: the size of table is a sample]

I appreciate any help or comments in advance, Thank you.

I don't know how to implement it in python

Comment: Not really a good practice to have "same header for multiple columns". Why you want to do that? only for display? how you gonna use this dataframe later in your code?

Comment: Well, I want to use these MFCCs separately. For example, from the whole data frame extract MFCC, then d-MFCC, and then dd-MFCC. for example: df['MFCC']

Comment: Then using a dictionary seems a better option as you don't seem to need the dataframe object, you could still use `d['MFCC']` and have an array on which you can perform whatever you want (even re-built a dataframe from this single array if you need)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multi-index dataframe. Something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ar1 = np.random.randint(5, size =(4, 3)) # create a numpy array of 4 rows and 3 columns with random integers in range 0 to 5
ar2 = np.random.randint(5, size =(4, 3)) # create another array
ar3 = np.random.randint(5, size =(4, 3)) # create another array

np_two = np.concatenate((ar1, ar2, ar3), axis=1) # create a 4x6 array by horizonatally concatenation

col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
    ])
data = pd.DataFrame(np_two, columns=col)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
  one       two       three      
    a  b  c   a  b  c     a  b  c
0   0  3  0   1  3  4     3  1  1
1   1  3  3   1  1  1     4  2  4
2   4  2  2   1  3  3     0  1  1
3   2  2  2   1  2  1     3  2  2
```